# inequality with a positive matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, positive-definite

Let 
$$
A=\left[
  \begin{array}{cc}
   a  & b\\
   \overline{b}  & c\\
  \end{array}
\right]$$ be a positive semi-definite positive of $M_2(\mathbb{C})$. How prove the inequality $ac \geq |b|^2$ ?

Comment: The inequality makes no sense unless those numbers are real, and even then the inequality would have to be the other way around for positiveness.

Comment: "semi-definite" positive imply "selfadjoint" hence $a,c$ are reals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For positive semi-definiteness, we need $z^*Az$ to be real and non-negative for all $z = [x, \;y]^T$ where $x, y \in \mathbb C$.  Thus we need
$$a|x|^2+c|y|^2+bx^*y+b^*xy^*$$
to be real and non-negative for every choice of $x, y \in \mathbb C$.

As we may have either of $x, y = 0$ it is immediate that $a, c$ must both be real and non-negative.

Further, selecting $x = b, y=t \in \mathbb R$ we have $a|b|^2+ct^2+2|b|^2t \ge 0$ which means we need by the discriminant condition, $|b|^4 \le ac|b|^2 \implies |b|^2 \le ac$ or $|b| = 0$.

In either case, $A$ being semi-definite implies $|b|^2 \le ac$.

Comment: We can also use the determinant(=product of eigenvalues)